# figuring out whether submissions were made on time or late

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a set of requirements which I can't yet decide the best way to implement.

I have a table in the database for submissions, including the date a submission was made (Submission.Name, Submission.Date).

Each year, we want the user to make 2 submissions, one by April 1, and one by December 1

The requirements indicate that we show the user a notification on the home page, which can be one of three:
 - submission completed for current period (green)
 - submission pending by end of current period (blue)
 - submission outstanding from previous period (red)

There is one additional rule which is that if a submission is overdue by more than 3 months, then 
we should display the submission pending notification (blue) for the upcoming deadline instead of the red one.

The problem is when trying to determine if a submission that is in the first 3 months of the current period should be counted towards the current period or if it was just a late submission for the period before (which would have been overdue).

Checking previous periods for whether or not they were overdue might also require checking their previous
period ...etc. making it more complicated than I hoped.

The options so far look like either to query the table using EntityFramework to calculate the state, or to implement this logic in code, however, both options appear non-trivial so far.

Can anyone see a better approach to this kind of problem? Or does anyone have any Linq tricks to do this in one shot?

**Edit:** we want 2 submissions per year, but the user is free to make more than 1 submission per period, and hence why it's difficult trying to interpret how the submissions correlate back to overdue periods

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you determine when a user's _first_ submission was supposed to be due? I mean, at any time you should be able to determine the number of due commissions a user must have done, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make it clear that the user can submit as many times as they wish during a particular period. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add a new field to your database, "LastSubmissionPeriod" and set it to 
April 1, or December 1 so you know which period has been filled?

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem, the hard part is to figure out if a particular submission should count towards the current period, or was it simply a late submission for the overdue period (hence, the problem is still there trying to piece together if prior periods were overdue or not)

Comment: When the last period submission has been done the LastSubmissionPeriod will be set to the last period, If not it will be set to the period prior to the one or even the one before that. so you can make sure the LastSubmissionPeriod always reflects the last submission to be filled. this has the advantage that even if one misses 2 or 3 submissions you can tell how many submissions are to be filled before the account is back in order

Comment: A submission is only counted towards the last period if it was overdue, never for prior periods. Hence, after the 3 months, if an overdue period wasn't filled, it will never be filled.

Comment: After working through it further yesterday, I ended up with a version of your answer. So thank you for your help.